# boto.dynamodb2: partial_save on existing item?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto

My goal: to simply update a single attribute of a record in DynamoDB.  I do not want to read the item first; I'm merely setting one of its attributes--I don't care what the attribute's previous value was, if any.

The problem: If the item already exists, boto throws a `ConditionalCheckFailedException`.

Some code that illustrates the problem:

```
from boto.dynamodb2.items import Item
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table
from time import time

table = Table('my_table')

data = {
    'the_key': '123456',
    'last_seen': time()
}

item = Item(table, data=data)
item.partial_save()
```

The first time I run this code (when item 123456 does not exist), it works fine.  Item 123456 is created and its `last_seen` attribute is set.

The second time I run the code, it blows up:

```
boto.dynamodb2.exceptions.ConditionalCheckFailedException: ConditionalCheckFailedException: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'The conditional request failed', u'__type': u'com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20120810#ConditionalCheckFailedException'}
```

---

Poking around the boto code, it looks like `partial_save` is setting an `expects` parameter that forces DynamoDB to check the attribute's previous value (and fail if it isn't what was expected).  I understand that boto is trying to help me from accidentally overwriting data that some other process may have updated.  But, in this case, I don't care about that; I simply want to blindly set the attribute value, even if that means it'll overwrite someone else's change.

Is there a way to do this using boto.dynamodb2?  (I cobbled together a working version using boto.dynamodb, but I'd really rather not use deprecated code.)

Comment: Have you tried the overwrite=True setting? As mentioned here for save(), maybe it's the same for partial_save(): http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamodb2_tut.html#updating-an-item

Comment: partial_save takes no `overwrite` argument.  If it did, my problem would be solved.